# Assembly: is #0x4 same as #4

Tags: assembly, arm

I am learning assembly language and would like to clarify about OFFSET.

I have learnt that

> LDR R9, [R0, #0x4]

This means that from R0's memory address, it will add 4 bits down to access the memory data.

However, is the above the same as

> LDR R9, [R0, #4]

Comment: `0x4` means the same as `4`, but `0x10` does not mean the same as `10`. The `0x` notation is hexdecimal, which shares the same digits only up to `9`.

Comment: Oh i see. so i was to put 0x10, it will access to the next 16 bits?
Thank you!

Comment: @TsuWeiQuan Note that a bit is not the same thing as a byte.  Each byte has its own address and each byte is made of eight bits.  So `[r0 + #0x10]` is indeed 16 bytes behind `[r0 + #0x00]`.

Comment: Alright! Sorry my mistake! it should be byte instead of bit.
Also, if #123 means it should be 123bytes behind #0x00?
which also means that #value is a static value?

Comment: when you assembled and then disassembled these two instructions was the machine code the same?

Comment: @old_timer i have not tried coding it out yet as i am still reading the theories. Will try soon :)

Comment: @TsuWeiQuan Yes, exactly.  The `#` sign is used to denote *immediate values* which are small constants directly embedded into instructions.

Comment: Alright! Crystal Clear! Thank You all for helping! Cheers

Comment: just trying it would have answered the question for the assembler you are using.